# Is it possible to get vendor-specific files (e.g. drivers) from a phone and use them in combination with AOSP?

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, custom-roms, aosp

I was wondering whether it's possible to get these files, because to use AOSP on a device, you need these even just to boot. They aren't publicly available from some vendors (IIRC Google provides them?), so I thought about getting them directly from the Android device. I have found some answers regarding where they are, but I don't know, if it's possible to use them from there, or even if there's an option to.

I know there are existing custom ROMs such as LineageOS, which for each device work out of the box, so that isn't a problem, regarding devices they support. But what about devices they don't support? For example the 2020 Samsung Galaxy Tab A7. They support the 2016 version, but not the 2020.

Comment: Some custom ROMs use the original kernel which contains the drivers and combine it with a new ROM.

Comment: To my knowledge no OEM officially provides binary blobs (userspace HALs). But they are bound to release kernel code due to GPL. Binary blobs are always extracted from a working device by custom ROM developers. And it's one of the steps in custom ROM development: https://wiki.lineageos.org/proprietary_blobs.html. // Please note that development related questions are off-topic here.